# __autoload disaster - conflicts with Joomla

Tags: php, autoload

I have just changed all my code to use __autoload to find that it conflicts with the joomla autoloader.  I integrate my app with joomla in some cases to register users etc.

I found spl_autoload_register() with aparently allows many autoloaders.

What should I do?

**update**: this is what joomla does

Loads this file from /library/loader.php

```
function __autoload($class)
{
    if(JLoader::load($class)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Update 2:**

OK, right after I load the Joomla library I call

```
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    //autoloader so that it does not interfere with mine
    spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

This is what my autoload looks like:

```
<?php

//IMPORT
function myAutoload($class_name)
{
    $path = str_replace('_', '/', $class_name);
    include $path . '.php';
}

?>

spl_autoload_register('myAutoload',false,true);
```

Mine gets called first and the joomla one second, however, the the app still can't find the Joomla classes.

**Update 3:**

After running:

```
echo "PRE: myAutoload:" . spl_autoload_functions() . "<br />";
spl_autoload_register('myAutoload',false,true);
echo "POST: myAutoload:" . spl_autoload_functions() . "<br />";
```

and

```
    echo "PRE: JoomlaAutoLoad:" . spl_autoload_functions() . "<br />";
    //autoloader so that it does not interfere with mine
    spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
    echo "POST: JoomlaAutoLoad:" . spl_autoload_functions() . "<br />";
```

My output was:
PRE: myAutoload:
POST: myAutoload:Array

### UPDATE 4:

I had to change the Joomla imports to this:

```
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'loader.php' );
    echo "PRE: JoomlaAutoLoad:" . var_dump(spl_autoload_functions()) . "<br />";
    //autoloader so that it does not interfere with mine
    spl_autoload_register('__autoload');

            echo "POST: JoomlaAutoLoad:" . var_dump(spl_autoload_functions()) . "<br />";

    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

Here is the output

```
PRE: myAutoload:
array
  0 => string 'myAutoload' (length=10)
POST: myAutoload:
array
  0 => string 'myAutoload' (length=10)
PRE: JoomlaAutoLoad:
array
  0 => string 'myAutoload' (length=10)
  1 => string '__autoload' (length=10)
POST: JoomlaAutoLoad:
```

I have worked out that after I include these Joomla files

```
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );
```

The spl_autoload_functions() returns nothing, so somehow joomla is stuffing it up.

Comment: Waht does spl_autoload_functions() return before and after your calls to spl_autoload_register() ?

Comment: If you want to know the content of an array, use print_r or var_dump instead of echo

Comment: ok, I have done sum stuff, I will update the question in about 2 minutes

Comment: looks like joomla has overriden the autoload array

Comment: You can test if both functions are executed when you try to instantiate a new object by adding echo "some string" at the beginning of both methods, but IMHO it won't work, because myAutoload() does not test whether a file exists before including it. I think you will just get a "no such file or directory" error when trying to include a Joomla class and that your script will stop after that (or does it continue anyway?).

Comment: I discovered that after adding the core joomla libraries, all the audoload function disappeared.

Comment: I think you should search Joomla's code for calls to 'spl_autoload_'-prefixed functions to see where and why this happens.

Answer (score 3):

you should decide which autoload function should have priority over the other one, and use `spl_autoload_register()` accordingly (look at the third argument). How is the Joomla autoload function registered?

Comment: I don't know how joomla is registered.  I know the file the autoloader comes from, but that is about all.  I will have a look now.

Comment: Ok, spl_autoload_register() is not used here, the conventional __autoload naming makes the registration automatic I suppose... let's hope this is compatible with spl_autoload_register(). Look at the documentation for spl_autoload_functions(), it says something about an autoload stack, which must be turned on. I think you should see if you get something else than false when you call this function after Joomla is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

I have most simple answer to this question, at least worked for me every time for joomla 1.5.22
::

```
require_once ( JPATH_SITE .DS.'libraries'.DS.'loader.php' );
spl_autoload_register('__autoload');
```

put these two lines before your own autoload register to give joomla preferance in stack

```
spl_autoload_register('DataMapper::autoload');
```

Comment: Yes, but be careful, the `'DataMapper::autoload'` syntax requires PHP 5.3

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record, just tried this solution and it works for me in Joomla 1.5:

1. Go to \libraries\loader.php(160)
   and replace

   ```
    function __autoload {...}
   ```

   with

   ```
   spl_autoload_register(array('JLoader', 'load'));
   ```
2. Now you've fixed the Joomla side of things.  You're actually
   done, there is no step 2.  But just for the record, I'd double-check
   that your own libraries also are playing nice and using
   spl_autoload_register.  If everyone is playing nice there should be
   no reference to any functions called __autoload anywhere anymore.

Voila.  Done.

To read a clear and concise explanation of why this works, go here:

http://www.nicollet.net/2010/06/autoloading-be-friendly-to-intruders/

Comment: Yep, that's the correct solution. Joomla defines `__autoload`, which disables the autoload stack, so you need to actually remove the `__autoload` definition to make it work (and replace with a function registration). And thanks for the reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

i did it other way, just calling this method in a helper:

```
public static function configureZend(){
    $params = self::getParameters();
    $zf_path = $params->get('zend_location');//this should be the zend framework directory location
    define( 'ZFLIBPATH', $zf_path );
    set_include_path( ZFLIBPATH );
    require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
    $loader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $loader->pushAutoloader(array('JLoader','load'),'');
}
```

works all right, doesnt need to change any source of the joomla core, and all zend clases work fine.